# Story where a judge/adjudicator is a large black cube

Tags: story-identification

I once read a SciFi book in which there was a special type of judge or adjudicator.

In this book the 'judge' is referred to

> "a large black cube over there. The size of a house."

To which the reply is,

> "How do I know it's a cube of that size? From this aspect I cannot see all of its sides and size is relative. Perhaps its not black, but very dark grey. You are feeding me your opinion without proof. Without scientific inspection or experience, I cannot reach a judgement on the matter."

Comment: Sounds vaguely like Jack Vance.

Comment: It's depressing how many stories feature black cubes the size of a house.

Answer (score 6):

Is it possible that you've got a slightly muddled memory of the concept of a "Fair Witness" in Robert A. Heinlein's *[Stranger in a Strange Land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stranger_in_a_Strange_Land)*?

> Jubal looked pained. "Little girl, count to ten thousand by twos while I
>   finish this. Ben did not catch them out. In fact, even the Honorable Mr.
>   Cavendish did not catch them out-at least he won't say so. You know how Fair
>   Witnesses behave."
>
> "Well ... no, I don't. I've never had any dealings with Fair Witnesses."
>
> "So? Perhaps you weren't aware of it. Anne!"
>
> Anne was seated on the springboard; she turned her head. Jubal called out,
>
> "That new house on the far hilltop-can you see what color they've painted it?"
>
> Anne looked in the direction in which Jubal was pointing and answered,
>
> "It's white on this side." She did not inquire why Jubal had asked, nor make any
>   comment.
>
> Jubal went on to Jill in normal tones, "You see? Anne is so thoroughly
>   indoctrinated that it doesn't even occur to her to infer that the other side is
>   probably white, too. All the King's horses and all the King's men couldn't force
>   her to commit herself as to the far side - . . unless she herself went around to
>   the other side and looked-and even then she wouldn't assume that it stayed
>   whatever color it might be after she left because they might repaint it as soon
>   as she turned her back,"